# Filtering maps in iterator

Tags: scala

I have following code:

```
val rows: Iterator[Map[String,String]] = CSVDictReader(file.getInputStream)
val parsedProducts = rows.map(x => Product(name = x.get("NAME"), id = x.get("ID")))
```

And I would like to replace map entries with empty string. With a map alone I could use:

```
filter(_._2.trim.nonEmpty)
```

I cannot get my head around how to do this in a nice way without introducing some helper function to return None in case value is empty string.

Edit: In my example I have only name and id but in the real code there are easily over ten columns of data. Also, I would need to have None instead of empty string value. So name=Option("") should be replaced with name=None

Comment: replace or remove? if you want to replace them, what would be an alternative to empty strings which you got from map?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `Option`s as well.

Let's say your `x.get("NAME")` returns a `Some("")` or even `Some("  ")`.

Then you may do something like this: `x.get("NAME").filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)`

Hope I understood your question correctly

Comment: Yep, that works but I would like to avoid replicating .filter(_.trim.nonEmpty) for each CSV field.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
val rows: Iterator[Map[String,String]] = CSVDictReader(file.getInputStream)
val parsedProducts = for {
    row <- rows 
    name <- row.get("NAME")
    id <- row.get("ID")
} yield Product(name, id)
```

Here, if row.get("NAME") or row.get("ID") return None, the corresponding entry will not be yielded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the following code snippet:

```
   val rows: Iterator[Map[String,String]] = Iterator(Map("NAME" -> " ", "ID" -> "foo"), Map("NAME" -> " ", "ID" -> ""))
   val fieldNames = List("NAME","ID","ANOTHER COLUMN")
   val cleanedRows = rows map { row =>
     fieldNames map { fieldName =>
       Map ( fieldName -> row.get(fieldName).filter (_.trim.nonEmpty) )
     }
   }

   while(cleanedRows.hasNext) {
     println(cleanedRows.next)
   }
```

Would print out:

```
   List(Map(NAME -> None), Map(ID -> Some(foo)), Map(ANOTHER COLUMN -> None))
   List(Map(NAME -> None), Map(ID -> None), Map(ANOTHER COLUMN -> None))
```

So at this point `cleanedRows` would have the entries you need to create your `Product` instances.